# use of ROLLBACK command in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rollback

I created table

```
SQL>CREATE TABLE Student
(
StudID         NUMBER(6),
StudName       VARCHAR2(25),
JoinDate       DATE
);   
Table created.

SQL>INSERT INTO Student
VALUES (123,'JOHN',SYSDATE);
1 row created.

SQL>DELETE Student;
1 row deleted.
```

How can I get back the row ?
If I use

```
SQL>ROLLBACK;
Rollback complete.
```

But after that

```
SQL>SELECT * FROM Student;
no rows selected.
```

Why is this coming?

Answer (score 22):

This might be a bit confusing if you are not doing rollbacks on a regular basis.
I put here mistakes that you are likely to make if not using SAVEPOINTS / ROLLBACK on a regular basis.

**1. This is your case. We rollback all transaction to the beginning, ie. to the last (implicit) commit**

[image]

---

**2. Here we have SAVEPOINT but it does not matter, as it is not mentioned in ROLLBACK statment. So we are rolling back to the last commit, as before.**

[image]

**3. This is tricky. The rollback still goes to the last commit, as the syntax was not correct (but no error reported by the 11g database). Correct syntax is ROLLBACK TO <SAVEPOINT-NAME>:**

[image]

**4. Finally we have correct SYNTAX: ROLLBACK TO <SAVEPOINT-NAME>**

[image]

Some readings:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9021.htm

Answer (score 16):

`ROLLBACK` tells Oracle to roll back the entire transaction. In your case, both the `INSERT` and the `DELETE` are part of the same transaction so the `ROLLBACK` reverses both operations.  That returns the database to the state it was in immediately following the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Some alternatives:

1. If you were to issue a `COMMIT` after the `INSERT` then the `DELETE` statement would be in a separate transaction and the `ROLLBACK` would reverse only the effect of the `DELETE` statement.
2. You could also create a savepoint after running the `INSERT` statement and then rollback to that savepoint after the `DELETE` rather than rolling back the entire transaction.

Comment: Instead of SQL> DELETE Student; I used SQL> DELETE FROM Student

Comment: 1 row deleted. Then used ROLLBACK; and then SELECT * FROM Student; and it works.

Comment: @bibhudash - What is not working?  Everything you have posted appears to be working as it is supposed to.  If that is not the behavior you want, you'll need to change your code.  That's why I gave you a couple of different options for how to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    CREATE TABLE your_table
     AS SELECT * FROM employees;

     ALTER TABLE your_table
     ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

     UPDATE your_table
      SET CON_TYPE = 'N';

    FLASHBACK TABLE your_table
       TO TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' minute);
           /*if you want to restore the table*/
       FLASHBACK TABLE print_media TO BEFORE DROP;

    /*Restore the table with other name*/
       FLASHBACK TABLE your_table TO BEFORE DROP RENAME TO your_table;
```